# data.table efficient recycling

Tags: r, data.table, recycle

I frequently use recycling in data.table, for exemple when I need to make projections future years.
I repeat my original data fro each future year.

This can lead to something like that :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(cbind(1:500000, 500000:1))
dt2 <- dt[, c(.SD, .(year = 1:10)), by = 1:nrow(dt) ]
```

But I often have to deal with millions of lines, and far more columns than in this toy exemple.
The time increases ..
Try this :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(cbind(1:50000000, 50000000:1))
dt2 <- dt[, c(.SD, .(year = 1:10)), by = 1:nrow(dt) ]
```

My question is : is there a more efficient to achieve this purpose ?

Thanks for any help !

EDIT : 
the accepted answer was the most complete (till now), for this formulation of the problem, but I realised that my issue is a little bit more tricky. 
I will ask another question in order to show it : [data.table efficient recycling V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197298/data-table-efficient-recycling-v2)

Comment: Have you  tried with `rep` on sequence of rows

Comment: Could it by XY problem. What is your final application?

Comment: Thank you Akrun, but I can't see how to take advantage of your advice ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm benchmarking the solutions given so far against my own (which simply uses `lapply` and `rbindlist`). I couldn't run the entire task because I run out of memory. That's why I choose a smaller dt:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(cbind(1:5000000, 5000000:1))

original <- function() {
  dt2 <- dt[, c(.SD, .(year = 1:10)), by = 1:nrow(dt) ]
  dt2
}

sb <- function() {
  dt2 <- dt[CJ(V1, year = 1:10), on = "V1"]
}

gregor <- function() {
  CJDT <- function(...) {
    Reduce(function(DT1, DT2) cbind(DT1, DT2[rep(1:.N, each=nrow(DT1))]), list(...))
  }
  years = data.table(year = 1:10, key = "year")
  setkey(dt)
  dt3 = CJDT(dt, years)
  dt3
}

bindlist <- function() {
  dt3 <- rbindlist(lapply(1:10, function(x) {
    dt$year <- x
    dt
  }))
  # dt3 <- setcolorder(dt3, c("nrow", "V1", "V2", "year")) # to get exactly same dt
  # dt3 <- dt3[order(nrow)]
  dt3
}
```

#### Benchmark

```
library(bench)
res <- mark(
  original = original(),
  sb = sb(),
  gregor = gregor(),
  bindlist = bindlist(),
  iterations = 1,
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
res
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 original      5.88s    5.88s     0.170    1.72GB   16.0  
#> 2 sb            1.76s    1.76s     0.570    1.73GB    0.570
#> 3 gregor        1.87s    1.87s     0.536  972.86MB    0    
#> 4 bindlist   558.69ms 558.69ms     1.79     1.12GB    0

summary(res, relative = TRUE)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   expression   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 original   10.5   10.5       1         1.81      Inf
#> 2 sb          3.14   3.14      3.35      1.82      Inf
#> 3 gregor      3.34   3.34      3.15      1         NaN
#> 4 bindlist    1      1        10.5       1.18      NaN
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now the results are not exactly the same (see commented code in my solution for correcting it) but equivalent to what you are trying to do. My `lapply` plus `rbindlist` solution is suprisingly the fastet by a factor of more than 3. This might change on the full task but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

I would think of this problem as a cross join. There is no built-in way to do cross joins between two data tables (the `CJ` function works on vectors), but from the discussion [on this issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1717#issuecomment-545758165), this function works well:

```
CJDT <- function(...) {
    Reduce(function(DT1, DT2) cbind(DT1, DT2[rep(1:.N, each=nrow(DT1))]), list(...))
}
```

Using your large example, this works for me:

```
years = data.table(year = 1:10, key = "year")
setkey(dt)
dt3 = CJDT(dt, years)
```

Where your method takes longer before running out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments I have a suspicion that the premise of the question might be *questionable*. In any case, here is a slightly faster alternative:

```
setkey(dt)
dt[CJ(V1, year = 1:10)]
```

*Benchmarking*:

```
dt <- data.table(cbind(1:50000000, 50000000:1))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  op = dt[, c(.SD, .(year = 1:10)), by = 1:nrow(dt) ],
  sb = {setkey(dt); dt[CJ(V1, year = 1:10)]},
  gr = {setkey(dt); CJDT(dt, data.table(year = 1:10, key = "year"))},
  times = 1
)
```

Unit: seconds

```
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   op 171.67241 171.67241 171.67241 171.67241 171.67241 171.67241     1
   sb 136.00782 136.00782 136.00782 136.00782 136.00782 136.00782     1
   gr  45.14151  45.14151  45.14151  45.14151  45.14151  45.14151     1
```

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking. Especially for big problems like this, I've started to prefer `bench::mark` to `microbenchmark` as it also keeps track of memory usage. If you look at the Github link in my answer, there are other proposals that are a little faster on large data, but use ~50% more memory.

Comment: You could also `setkey` before the benchmark---probably even OP's solution would benefit from it.

Comment: "the premise of the question might be questionable" ... what do you mean ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington is it really necessary to this enormous data.table for your final output?

Comment: For me, yes it is, of course. But anyway, your answer is interesting and I will study it.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for feedback. I tried to run again but `bench::mark()` ran out of memory.

Comment: @Gregor bench does not track memory usage properly, it is better to not look at that measure at all as it is misleading.

Comment: @jangorecki thanks---good to know. Do you have a reference where I could read more about that?